# How do the prizes from Conquest work?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I participated in some Conquests, and in some of them, my team won. But, the prizes seemed to have no correlation with the points I put in (In one round, I had 1 point, got 2000 Coins, but in another, put 4 points, and got 1000 Coins). How does the game decide what people get for participating? Is it a set prize, or does it depend on something else?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

Say "Team Red" has three characters: Charizard, Mario, and Ike.  "Team Blue" also has three characters: Mega Man, Sonic, and Lucario.

Every time you play as one of those characters and you *win*, you add a couple of points to that character's team (you can see how many points you contribute on the results screen after the fight where you used the character, indicated by a flag). The server adds up everyone's points contributed, and it generates a percentage, which is how the server decides which team wins. For example (again):

Say you fight and win four fights: one as Ike, one as Lucario, one as Pac-Man, and one as Mario. You'll contribute (let's say) 7 points to the Red Team by winning as Ike the first time (I don't know how much exactly), 7 points to the Blue Team by winning as Lucario, no points to no team for winning as Pac-Man, and another 7 points to the Red Team for your Mario victory.

Now, if you were the ONLY person in the world who played SSB online, the Red team would win because you contributed 14 points to the Red and 7 points to the Blue.

As for the prizes, you're right. It's all random. Realistically, millions of users play SSB online, so there would be no easy way to evenly dole out prizes among everyone. It's just like random classic mode victory prizes (or pretty much anything else).

Comment: So the prizes ARE completely random?

Comment: Yes. They are random.

Comment: "Realistically, millions of users play SSB online, so there would be no easy way to evenly dole out prizes among everyone." That would only be true if prizes were somehow given out manually, since they're given out automatically by the game, it would be very easy.